# Group 2(or more) consecutive days together in an NSMutableDictionary for core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

So i have several time spans such as week, biweek, month, and year and my graph can only hold 8 X-Variables. I need to be able to group consecutive days together so i can fit the days on the X-axis.the float ***previousProfit*** can be added for all of the grouped days. This is how I add the standard week

```
 for(NSString *date in dates) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(NSString *set in sets) {
        float previousProfit = [[profitForDate objectForKey:date] floatValue];
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:previousProfit];
        [dict setObject:num forKey:set];
    }
    [dataTemp setObject:dict forKey:date];
}

data = [dataTemp copy];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

I have the profit stored in an NSMutableDictionary for the key of each date.

My question is how to group dates into a certain number of groups, then retrieve the profit for each date

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine the earliest and latest date
2. Calculate time interval between them using `timeIntervalSinceDate:`
3. Divide the time interval into the number of intervals you want
4. Figure out the begin/end dates for each interval by repeatedly
   adding the interval to the start date
5. Use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` with `earlierDate:` and
   `laterDate:` to select dates that fall into each of the intervals
6. For each group of dates, get the data (keyed by date) and aggregate
   it for display in your graph.